# Voice Commands vs Voice Search

Tags: voice-recognition, voice-command

What is the difference in Voice Commands and Voice Search? Are they both by Google?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Voice Search](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.voicesearch&hl=en) is the name of the voice interaction app created by Google. It allows you to search your phone and the web using your voice.

Voice Actions is a specific *feature* of the Voice Search app that allows you to perform actions on your phone using your voice (such as calling someone, launching your music player, getting directions, etc). Voice Search supports a variety of locales but the Voice Actions component is only available for a subset of those (originally US English only, though I believe [it has since expanded](http://googlemobile.blogspot.com/2011/09/introducing-voice-actions-for-android.html)).

If you have a separate app named "Voice Commands" then it is most likely developed by a third-party. I know some Verizon phones, for instance, ship with an app named "Voice Commands" and bottom of the app displays `Nuance Communications copyright 2003-2011`.

Comment: In my list of app I have both Voice Search and Voice Commands. Are you saying the Voice Command app is really just a frontend tie-in to voice actions?

Comment: @Homer: Sorry, I think I made my answer more confusing that I intended. If you have a separate app named "Voice Commands" it's probably made by a third party. Google only has Voice Search (with Voice Actions) as far as I know.

Comment: And to add to the confusion there's also a "voice dialer" that's part of aosp.